# EMV Chip Working method

Tags: teaching

I would like to know how a EMV chip is working on a credit card and how it plays a vital role in banking transactions. What is the storage capacity of EMV chip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Academia.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have googled it. The Wikipedia states this

> ISO/IEC 7816-3 defines the transmission protocol between chip cards and readers. Using this protocol, data is exchanged in application protocol data units (APDUs). This comprises sending a command to a card, the card processing it, and sending a response. EMV uses the following commands:

- application block

  application unblock

  card block

  external authenticate (7816-4)

  generate application cryptogram

  get data (7816-4)

  get processing options

  internal authenticate (7816-4)

  PIN change / unblock

  read record (7816-4)

  select (7816-4)

  verify (7816-4).

> Commands followed by "7816-4" are defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4 and are
>   interindustry commands used for many chip card applications such
>   as GSM SIM cards.